# Disable qemu default shortcut

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, shortcut, qemu

I open freedos by qemu on Debian and I don't want the user switch it to Debian, but qemu monitor has shortcut "ctrl+alt+f", "ctrl+alt+m" and "ctrl+alt+2" which make the user has chance to leave qemu.
How to disable these qemu shortcuts?